# Can somebody please point out what is wrong with my Dockerfile? Also, please advise how can I convert this file to Alpine Linux?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, containers, dockerfile

```
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project myproject: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/automation/myproject/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project myproject: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/automation/myproject/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/automation/thanos/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete /home/automation/myproject/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /home/automation/myproject/ && mvn clean test-compile -e' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I need to execute my Selenium tests in Docker containers. I know Selenium provides hub and nodes containers but I have to write my own Dockerfile that will build a container which will execute tests with no grid configuration. Basically, I cannot use grid for some reason. I have written a Dockerfile. It fails at build stage and says unable to clean project.

I have tried opening firefox and chrome without adding any user i.e. tried to execute via root user but it didn't work. Then I added a user and still it does not work. Looks like permission is granted. Please point me where permission is needed and which one that is? Below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
LABEL name="Project short intro" \
            author="TAFSEER HAIDER" \
            version="1.0" \
            description="my project description"

# Install Java JDK8, Maven, and Wget
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install firefox  -y \
    && apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk \
    && apt-get install -y maven \
    && apt-get install -y wget \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


# Install Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Add a user for running applications.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install sudo -y \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' automation \
    && adduser automation sudo \
    && echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/ /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 

USER automation

# Copy myproject project to the specified directory in containerized Ubuntu Linux
COPY . /home/automation/myproject/


# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/automation/myproject/

# Clean & compile myproject
RUN cd /home/automation/myproject/ && mvn clean test-compile -e

# Execute tests on microservices and fronted GUI by specifying the required test suite file
CMD ["mvn", "failsafe:integration-test", "-DtestSuite=frontend.xml"]
```

It should execute my tests in headless mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `automation` user doesn't have [Linux write permission](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) hence he cannot remove `target` folder during [Maven `clean` phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Change this line:

```
COPY . /home/automation/myproject/
```

to this one:

```
COPY --chown=automation . /home/automation/myproject/
```

I also fail to see any real or [virtual display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) configuration in your Dockerfile, hopefully you pass `headless` arguments to the browsers initialization, otherwise your test will not work.

Also make sure to follow [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices), in particular:

- Use [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) to hold your WebDriver instances and the variables which are not meant to be global and shared across threads
- Avoid using [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) methods and fields
- Make sure that your tests are independent, repeatable and stable

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. for your response. Yes permission were not there for automation user. It is now fixed. And yes I am passing headless argument to initialize my browser and all practices you mentioned are already there in my framework.

Answer (score 0):

It might be ur automation user have no permission to delete some file, i saw u use automation user context to copy file

```
COPY . /home/automation/myproject/
```

but i saw another error at folder /home/automation/thanos....

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete /home/automation/thanos/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
```

You can try to change ownership or file permission for ur user

```
chown -R $YOUR_USER /home/automation/
```